# Sending Settings as JSON and using Reflection - SDK C#

Tags: c#, json, reflection, sdk

I'm creating a plugin SDK for my application. There are some static settings that are common between all plugins. I'm using an interface here to force SDK developers to use all of these static settings.

But Every plugin also has its own different settings which I can not add them to the SDK. Instead of I have added a string property in the interface so User should implement it and send plugin settings as a string in JSON format and every plugin should load and convert it to its necessary class or settings using reflection.

Is this process right for this situation?

Comment: In term of extensibility, I'd define your settings interface to have your sdk settings and a dictionary of custom settings (set as Dictionary<string, object>). Then the developers do or do not fill this dictionary with their extra custom properties.

Answer (score 1):

In term of extensibility, I'd define your settings interface to have your sdk settings and a dictionary of custom settings (set as Dictionary). Then the developers do or do not fill this dictionary with their extra custom properties.

(taken from my own comment as it may be a valid proposition)